# Powershell remoting write event log as non admin

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to set a non admin up with the ability to write events to the application log via powershell remotely. Remoting works, I can read the registry, etc. Just not write to the event log.

```
invoke-command -ComputerName myhost { write-eventlog -LogName Application -Source CMS -EntryType Information -EventID 200 -Message "Testing CMS event" }
```

The error is

```
The registry key for the log "Application" for source "CMS" could not be opened.
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Write-EventLog], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The registry key for the log "Application" for source "CMS" could not be opened.,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteEventLogCommand
```

The fix of changing the registry rights described doesn't work, and I can actually iterate the registry as the non admin user without issue:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName myhost { Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\system\currentcontrolset\services\eventlog\application\" }
```

I've seen a number of old articles regarding this issue.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552376/write-eventlog-within-function-over-remote-powershell) , [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/bec7d2c5-e60d-443d-97ac-805747b7674b/writeeventlog-on-remote-computer?forum=winserverpowershell) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/bec7d2c5-e60d-443d-97ac-805747b7674b/writeeventlog-on-remote-computer?forum=winserverpowershell)

I have tried enabling auditing on this key (which shows no access) and using procmon on both the client machine.  How do I get this working?

Comment: Can you invoke this as your non-admin user? `Invoke-Command -ComputerName myhost {New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\system\currentcontrolset\services\eventlog\application\" -Name "Test" -Value "JustTesting" -PropertyType "String"}`

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem, modifying the permission using wevtutil.exe worked for me.  Happy SDDL editing!

[Writing to the Windows Event Log from an ASP.NET or ASP application fails.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2028427/writing-to-the-windows-event-log-from-an-asp-net-or-asp-application-fa)